# Deleting vertices and edges

Tags: modeling, vertices

In the attached image how can I delete the 2 highlighted vertices and edge and leave the surrounding edges, faces intact?[image]

When I hit 'X' and select 'vertices', a gaping hole is created with adjoining faces/edges deleted.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

In *Edge Select* mode (keyboard shortcut <kbd>2</kbd>), select the edge you want to get rid of, press the space bar and type [dissolve](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/meshes/editing/mesh/delete.html)... then choose *Dissolve Edges*.

[image]

Answer (score 6):

To remove an edge while keeping surrounding geometry, in Blender terminology you *Dissolve* it.

This can be done 2 ways:

- <kbd>Delete</kbd> then **Dissolve Edges** or...
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd>
  *(when you're in edge mode - since this is context-sensitive dissolve - which dissolves verts/edges/faces based on the current mode).*