# How to have round edges when I subdivide with a subsurface modifier?

Tags: subdivision-surface

[image]

In the image you can see sharp edges, this problem was originated because I subdivided (Key "W" then Subdivide) the selected faces with a subsurface modifier of 4 subdivisions.

How do I make these sharp edges convert into round edges like a "Normal" subsurface modifier? Or like the edges of a cylynder/sphere.

NOTE: I need a lot of polygons-vertices because I have a "displace modifier", maybe you can help me find a way for displace modifier (With not a lot of polygons) instead of resolving this one.

I have tried with:

1. Smooth modifier, result is good on another mesh but with an error too, but in this one isn't working as I expect.
2. Smooth tools. It's quite good for my displacement modifier but it doesn't resolve the sharp edges.

EDIT:

3. Doesn't work with Subdivide Smooth too.

EDIT2:

[image]

What I want is everything marked with the red circle (The sharp/hard edges) turn into soft edges like the surface of a cylinder.

The problem is that I requires subdivide and the subsurface modifier because of the displace modifier (I need a lot of polygons).

Thanks for the answer.

Comment: Can you add your ref image of what you are expecting?

Comment: If Subdivide Smooth doesn't work, that suggests that there is varying density in the longitudinal edges, or they have a Crease value. Perhaps we can see your topology?

Comment: Thanks for the comment, just added an image in the post.

Comment: Anyone please??

Answer (score 1):

#### Simplify the base mesh

You can start with a very simple object and give it one *Subdivision Surface* modifier to smooth the shape.

[image]

#### Build the extra geometry with modifiers

Below the first modifier, you can add a second set to Simple to generate more geometry **without** affecting the overall shape.

[image]

Displacement works as usual.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Remove unnecessary edges(follow [this](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/41837/deleting-vertices-and-edges) instruction) after that you could add your modifier

Comment: Everything is necessary... for my displace modifier. I also followed the instruction, removing some edges but it seems that it doesn't work well if I don't remove more vertices, but that is the problem, I need the polygons for the displace modifier.

Comment: Instead, use simplified geometry and one subdivision modifier set to catmull-clark, and then another subdivision modifier set to simple for the additional geometry.