# How do i remove single vertex without removing face/corresponding vertices

Tags: modeling, edit-mode, vertices

I want to remove this vertex to create a straight line between the vertices on either side. If i delete it, it will remove the attached face too. Is there a simple, easy way to remove it and have the face automatically adjust to the new shape?
[image]

Comment: to add to Harry's answer, the shortcut for dissolve is Ctrl X

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Select the vertex and press <kbd>X</kbd> then *Dissolve Vertices* instead of delete. Another shortcut is <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>X</kbd>. Similar `dissolve` actions can be done with edges and faces too. See [Deleting vertices and edges](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/41837/deleting-vertices-and-edges)